# Allow public access to Staging website, but block access to CMS by IP

Tags: configuration

I'm looking to limit access to Staging **CMS** by IP. At the same time, the Staging website should be accessible to anyone irrespective of the IP.

The website is hosted on Azure App Service. 
I configured access restrictions by IP, however that blocks access to the Staging website too.
Is there a way I can block access only for the **CMS** and not the website?

Comment: Are your CM and CD roles on the same App Service then?

Comment: No, they're on two different app services.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, you want to block the access to cm.yourdomain.com/sitecore but not to cm.yourdomain.com?

Comment: Okay, so maybe it’s what Vinicius is saying then because you would otherwise use the “IP Restrictions” settings under “Networking” on your CM app service, publish content to the “web” database, and then view the site on the CD, where there are no restrictions.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think you have this option OOTB in the Azure Web App, and you might need to take a look at Azure Application Gateway or other firewall solution that handles Layer 7 requests. Please have a look here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5093237-36ce-4082-99c9-f14dd3faf715/block-a-url-path-with-azure-application-gateway?forum=websitesvirtualmachinesonwinserver

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps - Thank you will check using Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you want the following

- Allow access to https://cm.yourdomain.com
- Deny access to https://cm.yourdomain.com/sitecore

Azure Web App does not offer such feature, and you will need to add a firewall able to handle [Layer 7](https://www.twistlock.com/2018/10/23/know-firewall-layer-3-vs-layer-7/).

From perspective for Azure Application Gateway, you could try using custom rules:

In Azure, you have Azure Application Gateway, and try to address your need by using [custom rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview)

> Allowing and blocking traffic is simple with custom rules.  For
>   example, you can block all traffic coming from a range of IP
>   addresses.  You can make another rule to allow traffic if the request
>   comes from a specific browser.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301639/how-to-restrict-access-to-some-url-path-of-azure-web-service-from-internet

I haven't tested myself but please share your findings later on

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I will look into this and get back with the findings.

Comment: I could not get this working since we're using Sitecore 9.0 XP and WAF is supported from 9.1 onwards. Will give this a shot after we upgrade.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/682999